# Missing semicolon in code

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-sheets-api

I can't  find the error at line 27 in the test function:

```
var rowValues[column-2] = range.getValues();
```

My Code:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];

var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
var lastColumn = sheet.getLastColumn();

var now = new Date();    

function test() {

   for (row = 2; row < lastRow ; row++) {

        range = sheet.getRange(row, 1, 1, 1);  
        dateAdd = range.getValues();

        range = sheet.getRange(row, 5, 1, 1);  
        dateValidation = range.getValues();

        timeDiff = Math.abs(now.getTime() - Date.parse(dateAdd));
        diffDays = Math.ceil(timeDiff / (1000 * 3600 * 24)); 

        if (diffDays==1 &&  dateValidation==""){
            for (column = 2; column < lastColumn ; column++) {
                range = sheet.getRange(row, column, 1, 1);  
                rowValues[column-2] = range.getValues();
            }

          MailApp.sendEmail("xxxx@xxx.xxx","Subject %n","Description:  \n %d \n %d \n %d",row,rowValues[0],rowValues[1],rowValues[3]);
        }

      } 

    }
```

Comment: `var rowValues[column-2]` is invalid. You probably just meant `rowValues[column-2]` without the `var`. `var` is used for declaring variables, not array indices.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've found the solution:

```
range = sheet.getRange(row, column, 1, 1);  
rowValues.push(range.getValues());
```

Answer (score 4):

You have used an extra `var` where you shouldn't have one - essentially you've done this:

```js
var array = [];
var array[0] = "foo";
```

Where you should have this:

```js
var array = [];
array[0] = "foo";
```

So change this line of your code:

```
var rowValues[column-2] = range.getValues();
```

to

```
rowValues[column-2] = range.getValues();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to update this line:

**Here:**

```
    var rowValues[column-2] = range.getValues();
```

**To:**

```
    rowValues[column-2] = [];
    rowValues[column-2].push(range.getValues());
```